# Is there a C++ equivalent to roslib.get_ros_home()?

Tags: ros, c++, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In python, it's possible to use roslib.get_ros_home() to query the environment for the ROS_HOME environment variable, and fall back to HOME/.ros if it doesn't exist. This is very useful for finding a directory that ROS processes can use for storing their own logs or other temporary data.

Is there any equivalent to this in C++?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127601/is-there-a-c++-equivalent-to-roslib.get_ros_home()-?/) by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

Inside [roscpp/src/libros/file_log.cpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/hydro-devel/clients/roscpp/src/libros/file_log.cpp) they use:

```
std::string ros_log_env;
get_environment_variable(ros_log_env, "ROS_HOME")
```

But I wasn't able to figure out where *get_environment_variable* comes from (is it a system call? is it a custom fucntion?... no idea).

I hope this hint would help you

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-09**:
Thanks! I suspect the get_environment_variable uses the standard C `getenv` function somewhere underneath. Looking into file_log.cpp some more, it looks like they're implementing the fallback logic by hand rather than using a library function for it. I suspect I'll have to do the same in my code.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-08-30**:
For the record, comes from [roscpp_core/cpp_common/include/ros/platform.h](http://answers.ros.org/question/127601/is-there-a-c-equivalent-to-roslibget_ros_home/)

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-08-31**:
Hi Daniel, thanks for pointing that out! Could you, please, check the link that you posted? It currently points to http://answers.ros.org/question/127601/is-there-a-c-equivalent-to-roslibget_ros_home/ instead of the file that you mention. Thanks!

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2016-07-18**:
https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/blob/dca523422ca13ffc1aacf08ad3b213796465b624/cpp_common/include/ros/platform.h#L63